# JSON deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

У меня есть два Entity класса `Route` и `Notification`.

В `Route` есть поле `List(Notification) @OneToMany` а в `Notification` поле `Route route @ManyToOne, JoinColumn(route_id)`, соответственно 2 таблицы в БД.

Если не использовать анотации `@JsonManagedReference` и `@JsonBackReference`, то при десериализации (POST метод JSON) ошибка, тк

```
route_id ForeignKey cannot be null
```

А если использовать эти аннотации, то обе таблицы заполняются данными. Суть вопроса - как работают данные 2 аннотации?

Answer (score 1):

> For avoiding the problem, linkage is handled such that the property annotated with @JsonManagedReference annotation is handled normally (serialized normally, no special handling for deserialization) and the property annotated with @JsonBackReference annotation is not serialized; and during deserialization, its value is set to instance that has the "managed" (forward) link.

Т.е. поле, помеченное анотацией `@JsonManagedReference` сериализуется как если бы аннотации не было, а  `@JsonBackReference` не сериализуется совсем, а при десериализации использует данные из поля, помеченного `@JsonManagedReference`.

Сделсано это для того, чтобы избежать бесконечной рекурсии(когда у вас есть список `Notification` в каждом из которых есть объект `Route`, в котором есть список `Notification`...

Comment: Все понятно кроме одного, при десериализации использует данные из поля помеченного @JsonManagedReference (у меня это поле List of Notification) он подставляет в route_id инстанц Notification? Что это даёт? В этом поле должен быть ID из таблицы Routes..

Comment: Ну, при десериализации `route_ id` превращается в объект `Route`(когда вы мапите ваш json на entity)